# killing an xterm opened with -hold

Tags: process, xterm, xkill

I can kill a terminal opened with `xterm -hold` by typing `xkill` and then clicking the left mouse button.     But I'd like to avoid the need for the click.      I would have expected that

```
xkill -id `echo $$`
```

would work, but it throws an error.  Could somebody please tell me how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, the manual description is not clear, but you need to specify the window ID, not the PID. In Xterm,

```
xkill -id "$WINDOWID"
```

In all terminals,

```
xkill -id "$(xdotool getactivewindow)"
```